# Elegant way to delete a paragraph with python-docx?

Tags: python, python-docx

Sometimes it's useful to make a paragraph disappear from an already existing docx file. This is relatively easy to do with:

```
paragraph.text = ''
```

In wonder whether there is a cleaner way to remove the paragraph itself (i.e. from the relevant xml code in `document.xml`) using python-docx?

Would there be advantages to do that? Or is it not worth the trouble?

Comment: May be, this can help - https://stackoverflow.com/q/29283306/2650427.

Comment: Thanks, more precisely, here is the link to the answer: https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/33#issuecomment-77661907